# Как правильно получить список элементов через BeautifulSoup

Tags: python-3.x, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

При выполнении кода выводится пустой список [], хотя искомые элементы в коде есть и подтягиваются не Ajax'ом, проблема возникает в случае если указываются два и более фильтра то есть `find_all('a',class_='item')`, при `find_all('a')`, все работает корректно, печатает все ссылки.
Пример кода:

```
def get_html(url, params = None):
    r = requests.get(url, headers = HEADERS, params = params)
    return r

def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a',class_="item-serial")
    print(items)

def parse():
    html = get_html(URL)
    if html.status_code == 200:
        get_content(html.text)
    else:
        print('Error')

parse()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте кусок HTML, мало данных.

Comment: А лучше ссылку на страницу, с четки пояснением того, что хотите получить в результате

Comment: И еще, я может чтото пропустил, но где Вы увидели тег `a` принадлежащий классу `item-serial` в вашем исходнике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот эту функцию

```py
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    items = soup.find_all('a',class_="item-serial")
    print(items)
```

как мне кажется, нужно немного переделать

```py
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    # Если ссылки нужно получить то div.a['href'] если названия то div.a.text.strip()
    items = [div.a['href'] for div in soup.find_all('div',class_="field_title")]
    print(items)
```

Ну вот так как-то

Answer (score 0):

В вашем коде указано что элемент имеет тип `a` (эквивалент - `<a></a>`) и имеет класс `class="item-serial"`, но на странице искомый элемент `а` находится внутри контейнера `div` с таким классом, а сам элемент `a` не имеет классов вообще.

Ваш код можно представить строками:

```py
def get_content(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
    div_elements = soup.find_all('div',class_="item-serial")
    a_elements_in_divs = [div_element.find_all('a') for div_element in div_elements]
    print(a_elements_in_divs)
```

В этом коде мы в каждом контейнере с выбранным классом ищем элемент `a`. В итоге получается список (`div`) со списками (`a`).

*(Конечный результат можно [распаковать](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists), если в этом есть необходимость.)*